Unable to update JSON object in LWC throwing :1 Uncaught (in promise) error
I have a wire function where i am getting data from apex
get userAddressBookData() {
var selectedUserListBeforeApexCall =  this.selectedAddressList;
console.log('selectedUserListBeforeApexCall---',JSON.stringify(selectedUserListBeforeApexCall))
for(var i=0;i<this.selectedAddressList.length;i++)
{
let selectedShippingMethodId = this.selectedAddressList[i].selectedShippingMethodId;
let selectedShippingMethod = this.shippingMethodListData.find(
shippingmethod => shippingmethod.Id === selectedShippingMethodId
);
console.log('selectedShippingMethod---',JSON.stringify(selectedShippingMethod))
if (selectedShippingMethod && selectedShippingMethod.ApprovalRequired__c)
{
// let approvalRequired  = this.selectedAddressList[i].isApprovalRequiredForShippingMethod;
// approvalRequired = true;
// console.log('here in')
// this.selectedAddressList[i].isApprovalRequiredForShippingMethod = approvalRequired;
// console.log('this.selectedAddressList[i].isApprovalRequiredForShippingMethod---',JSON.stringify(this.selectedAddressList[i].isApprovalRequiredForShippingMethod))
                this.selectedAddressList[i] = {
                    ...this.selectedAddressList[i], // Spread operator to copy the existing object
                    isApprovalRequiredForShippingMethod : true // Update the specific property
                };

            }
       }

}
based on some condition I am getting data but I am unable to update it it says uncaught in promise
please somebody help me as I am new to LWC
 
                                The selected shipping method requires approval. This order will be submitted for shipping method approval.
                              
this is the HTML code
this is the main template
[{"isApprovalRequiredForShippingMethod":false,"isCheckboxClicked":true,"quantity":0,"selectedAddress":{"Id":"a08DF00000GZqVeYAL","Name":"AB-00000","City__c":"Travenieer","Destination_Name__c":"ALex-Travenieer","Shipto_Company__c":"Folio","Shipto_Name__c":"ALex","State__c":"a05DF000007R2kYYAS","Address__c":"221b Bakers Street","Active__c":true,"State__r":{"State_Name__c":"Florida","Country__c":"a04DF00000DyUUyYAN","Id":"a05DF000007R2kYYAS","Country__r":{"Country_Code__c":"US","Country_Name__c":"United States","Id":"a04DF00000DyUUyYAN"}}},"selectedShippingMethod":{},"selectedShippingMethodId":"a06DF00000FkZOUYA3"},{"isApprovalRequiredForShippingMethod":false,"isCheckboxClicked":true,"quantity":0,"selectedAddress":{"Id":"a08DF00000GZt3eYAD","Name":"AB-00001","City__c":"Culver City","Destination_Name__c":"Jonathan Boulangeat-Culver City","Shipto_Company__c":"Folio Fine Wine Company","Shipto_Name__c":"Jonathan Boulangeat","State__c":"a05DF000007R2kYYAS","Address__c":"5632 Canterbury Drive","Active__c":true,"State__r":{"State_Name__c":"Florida","Country__c":"a04DF00000DyUUyYAN","Id":"a05DF000007R2kYYAS","Country__r":{"Country_Code__c":"US","Country_Name__c":"United States","Id":"a04DF00000DyUUyYAN"}}},"selectedShippingMethod":{},"selectedShippingMethodId":"a06DF00000FkZOUYA3"}]
this is the JSON data
